# Count sibling classes of ontology (from .owl) file using Java

Tags: java, jena, ontology, siblings

I wanted to count number of sibling classes in generated ontotoly using Java (Jena). I need to take this result for all the classes in ontology. Is there any method to take/count sibling classes in ontology. (And also, if super class is same then we can take it as a sibling class). As a example, in this image, final results will be A=0, B=1,C=1,D=1,E=1,F=2,G=2,H=2 .    [image].

```
              m.read("http://localhost/bbbbb/ontology.owl");
              ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classes = m.listClasses(); 

              int sum=0;
              for (classes.siblings(true); classes.hasNext();) ------???
              {
                sum ++;
                classes.next();
               }
```

Comment: Note that depending on whether you have a reason attached, the number of sibling classes can be different.  In owl, a class can have more than one parent, which also means that you'll want to be precise about which classes count as siblings:those with a common parent?  Those with at least one common parent?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have generated small ontology like above image. Yes, I only need to count sibling classes which has common parent. How can I do it using Java/Jena. I couldn't find a way for that until now. Are there any special method for that?

Comment: You could use get getSuperClass to get the super class, and then getSubClass to get the subclasses of that, count them, and subtract one.  You could even do it with a SPARQL query.

Comment: But do note that this *really* isn't quite the way that you should expect OWL classes to work.  OWL classes are much more like sets.  Your A is a superclass of D just as much as B is, so in some sense C is just as much a sibling of D as E is.

Comment: I have got your point.Thank you very much. First ,I will try to do it like what I have mentioned before.

Comment: I also have the same problem. My question is ------ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678156/count-number-of-sibling-classes-in-generated-ontology-using-java      ------If anyone have a solution please help me too. I tried using getSuperClass  and  getSubClass. But coun't take a answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor    and  Emalka    Sorry, I couldn't solve it yet.