# Take name and count number of sibling classes in generated ontology using Java

Tags: java, jena, ontology, spquery

I first generated the ontology. It was successful. Then, I want to take sibling classes name for each class and count number of sibling classes of each class in the generated ontology.As a example,

```
    Main super class- A
    Two sub classes of A - B , C
    Three sub classes of B- D, E
```

I tried using following code. I used getSuperClass to get the super class, and then getSubClass to get the subclasses of that. I used arraylist for first take name of each sibling classes. So, in above example output should be like,

```
 [C] [B] [E] [D]
```

In above output, 1st one for B's sibling, 2nd one for C's sibling......I used Jena for generate ontology. ( I heared about SPARQL query, but I am very new to it.)

Following code only for get sibling class name. It gave nullpointer error. But seems like output is correct with full link. How to separate last part?

```
public ArrayList<String> countSiblingClasses(String ontoClass) {

    ontologyCreation();
    this. m.read("http://localhost/new/onto1.owl");
     ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classes = ((OntModel) m).listClasses(); 

     ArrayList<String> siblingsName = new ArrayList<String>();
     while (classes.hasNext()) {

    OntClass all= (OntClass) classes.next();
    String cls = all.getSuperClass().listSubClasses().toSet().toString();
    System.out.println("class names="+cls);

    siblingsName.add(cls);
   }
    return siblingsName; 
}
```

It gave out put,

```
Exception in thread "main"  class names=[http://localhost/new/E, http://localhost/new/D]
 class names=[http://localhost/new/E, http://localhost/new/D]
 class names=[http://localhost/new/C, http://localhost/new/B]
 class names=[http://localhost/new/C, http://localhost/new/B]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Final_Cal.OntologyCreation2.countSiblingClasses(OntologyCreation2.java:235)
    at Final_Cal.OntologyCreation2.main(OntologyCreation2.java:34)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a HashMap? Is there a reason why a tree wouldn't work here?

Comment: Thank u for your reply. What is you mentioned by tree? ontology is tree type highrarchy. I used HashMap for future procedure of my project. Ok if I avoid HashMap part and just want to take name of sibling classes  and each number of sibling classes. Then can u give me some idea?                  I used " String cls = all.getSuperClass().listSubClasses().toSet().toString().;"  . this give out put like "[http://localhost/first/B, http://localhost/first/C .  How to separate  only last part as [B  , C ]?

Comment: Java debugging: which line is the NPE on? look at that line and detemine where the NPE is from. Create the line up if necessary.  Print `all` to determine which iteration of the loop you can in.

Comment: [localhost/first/B, localhost/first/C] splitting each string based on "/" and accessing the last index of the returned array will yield B or C. Can you post a sample that will allow us to recreate the NPE? Please refer to this link on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your post.

Comment: @DebosmitRay  Thank you very much for reply. I could found NPE. It is because of Superclass became null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc for `OntClass.getSuperClass()` says:

> A super-class of this class or null

`A` will not have a superclass.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes ,it is a reason for Null pointer exception. I used if( all.hasSuperClass())  for avoid it.